PutHDFS Nifi issue
Good morning, i want to create a Nifi flow from a certain URL to my HDFS. I created my HDFS cluster locally with my personal build and my Dockerfile and it is working, but when i try to use the the PutHDFS processor i have the issue described in the pic. I also created my own Nifi docker build with my Dockerfile and inside the source folder of my Nifi build i copied the hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml files of hte hadoop cluster that i'm using; obviously in my Dockerfile i added the following lines:
ADD --chown=nifi:nifi hadoop/core-site.xml /opt/nifi/core-site.xml

ADD --chown=nifi:nifi hadoop/hdfs-site.xml /opt/nifi/hdfs-site.xml


Someone have any idea? I just want to put the file in an HDFS folder named /folder01 that i successfully created in my HDFS bash.

It seems a problem on the HDFS side (permission to write to folder)

The permissions of the XML files isn't relevant to the error.
The Nifi container is running as nifi unix user, but the HDFS folder is owned by a user named root and doesn't allow write access by other users.
Since using root user in containers is not recommended, you can either use hdfs chown to correct the HDFS permissions, or you could maybe add HADOOP_USER_NAME=root as an environment variable for Nifi container, which should let it write to that directory, assuming the Hadoop cluster doesn't have any enabled security features (it doesn't, by default).
